# Kali Linux Wireless

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, airmon-ng

I am currently running Kali Linux 2.0 on VMWare. When I do airmon-ng it shows

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory
```

I looked in some threads and they told me to use an external network adapter device ( or something like that ) but I can't afford to buy things in the meantime. So is there any way for me to eliminate that error with my internal network adapter?

Thanks,

EDIT: Guess I have no other option beside buying an external network adapter then xD

Comment: Ok, so what are you trying to do? Hack the nets or simply access Internet from the VM? (I mean open browser and type some address like duckduckgo.com)

Comment: I'm trying to hack the net :D I can already access Internet with the shared internet

Comment: ok'e'then it's true - you need another wireless card (dongle). Here is a decent guide on your choices: http://www.wirelesshack.org/top-kali-linux-compatible-usb-adapters-dongles-2015.html

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I do not have access to online shopping. There is one shop near my house that sell this: http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dwa-131-wireless-n-nano-usb-adapter Do you think that usb adapter will work?

Comment: Well, IMO the best 'just work' chipset are `Atheros AR9271`. TP-LINK TL-WN722N usually has that one (but not always and you have to double-check). As of that one you have in your local store - you could try but I bet it would require a good portion of dancing around a fire and yelling to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to buy TP-Link to access wireless internet in VMware.Without this,you won't be able to access internet in VMware.
I bought model

`TP-Link TL-WN723N 150Mbps Mini Wireless N USB Adapter (White)`.

Comment: What, really? You mean you can't access internet in the VM without additional dongle? Its' definitely true when you want to sniff the network and you need a secondary wireless card for that but simply using the internet should work.

Comment: If you are using Kali/Backtrack Linux in your VMware,it won't work.few years back,I have faced the same issue.Simply using the internet will not work for VMware. You need to connect TP-link to your computer to access internet in VMware.

Comment: That's weird. I even want to check. Because `virtualbox` makes it automatically. `Qemu/KVM` requires to bridge a connection but it's an another story. UPDATE: ok, I checked and it works. All you need is guest additions and `vmnet` module running on your host (arch linux)